# DirectoryEntry CommitChanges() is throwing Access Denied error

Tags: c#, winforms, active-directory

I am working on Active Directive Role modification module in my project and getting Access denied error while Adding/Removing the roles of users. I am Administrator of AD server.

I noticed one schenario which is given below.

1: New user added in AD without any role.

2: Applying any role for user -(Getting error Access denied)

3: If apply the Super User role then role added successfully.

Code is given below

```
  // Search for role in Adam.
        DirectorySearcher directorySearcher = new DirectorySearcher(GetAdamSdsRoot());
        directorySearcher.Filter = "(&(objectCategory=group)(cn=" + roleName + "))";
        SearchResult searchResult = directorySearcher.FindOne();

        // Remove user from role.
        DirectoryEntry directoryEntry = searchResult.GetDirectoryEntry();
        directoryEntry.Properties["member"].Remove("<SID=" + GetActiveDirectoryUserSid(userName) + ">");
        directoryEntry.CommitChanges();
```

Answer (score 0):

For one, this isn't going to work:

```
directoryEntry.Properties["member"].Remove("<SID=" + GetActiveDirectoryUserSid(userName) + ">");
```

The `member` attribute is a list of `distinguishedName` attributes of the members, not their SIDs. So you need to remove the user's `distinguishedName`, not the SID.

But if that was the only problem, the exception would not be "Access denied".

I know you said you are an administrator, but are you running this under your administrator credentials?

Comment: Yes, I am running under the administrator account. Also noticed one more things that is given below. 1: There is 9 role on server. two is parent role and 7 is child folder role. If I assigned parent role then it work and if assigned child role then showing error. 2: If I assigned parent role and again updating child role then not getting access denied iissue.

Comment: Have you changed your code to use the `distinguishedName` of the user and not the SID?

Comment: Yes, I changed but getting diff error : "information: An invalid dn syntax has been specified.". My DN is "CN=singh Arunkumar,OU=Consultants,OU=Users,OU=SE,OU=CRFREE,DC=CRFREE,DC=com"/ Code line : directoryEntry.Properties["member"].Remove("<distinguishedName=" + GetActiveDirectoryUserDistinguishedName(userName) + ">");

Comment: You don't need the "<distinguishedName=" . You just pass the DN to the Remove method.

Comment: So in your case: `directoryEntry.Properties["member"].Remove(GetActiveDirectoryUserDistinguishedName(userName))`

Comment: Hi, Still getting same access denied error after suggested change :(

Comment: Then it must be a permission issue. Can you open the group in AD Users and Computers under the same credentials and modify the group membership there?

Comment: Yes, I modied and its working. I noticed one more thing. few of the role is giving me access denied error and rest all working. ALso if working role asigned and again assigning the role same role which was not working earlier, now we can assigned and not getting any access denied error.

Comment: Could you please come on skype "arunsinghdeveloper"?

Comment: I don't use Skype, but we can start a chat here. It will probably suggest that we do after a couple more messages... but is it the `CommitChanges()` line that's throwing the exception?

Comment: Or is it `FindOne()`?

Answer (score 0):

I know that this thread is old. But recently I worked in an API integration with AD to create and update users programmatically to an on-premise AD (on Windows Server 2012 R2).

I faced this issue: access denied error.

After a better understanding about LDAP connection handling I find that making it in the right way, we solved it. Next article was my base for this scenario. A really good example.

https://ianatkinson.net/computing/adcsharp.htm#ex5 (create_user section).